# Google Map with suburb with placeholders for areas of service

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

How could I use Google Maps within my website to show users of the website, suburb locations relating to areas of service?

I basically would like through the use of Google Maps, add placeholders on particular suburbs for a specific area that might cover, say 10 different suburbs.

From this, I would then like to place into a page on my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm using WordPress to host my Google Map, I managed to locate a decent Google Maps plugin for WordPress that let's me achieve what I am after.

For anybody else interested, I used the following plugin for this WordPress site:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comprehensive-google-map-plugin/